# MMA Function is not recognizing an input parameter to PrependTo Statement

Tags: functions

I am getting an error in the following code? What is the error telling me? How to fix?

```
list1 = {1, 2, 3};
list2 = {4};
i = 3;

Function[x_] = Block[{x, i, list1, list2},
  i = 3;
  while[i > 0,
     list2 = PrependTo[list2, list1];  
        i = i - 1;
   Print[x, list2]
   ]   ]  
;
```

Error:
PrependTo::rvalue: list2 is not a variable with a value, so its value cannot be changed.

Thank you. Mary A. Marion

Comment: You have to initialize `list2`, e.g. by `list2={}`. Btw.: It's `While`, not `while` in Mathematica. Please make sure that your example code is runnable.

Comment: Why are you `Block`ing `list1` and `list2`? Because you are, `list2` has no value, so you cannot prepend anything to it. Also, you need to decide to either use `list2 = Prepend[...]` or just `PrependTo[list2,...]`, not the combination you are using now

Comment: And `Function[x_] = ` is completely meaningless...

Comment: This was an example given in a recent training session. I am to debug it apparently. Answering your comments in turn... When I use While none of my code is working